# How to create a new cache region for a specific flexible search query?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

In Hybris, I need to create a new cache region for a specific flexible search query but not all queries.

Answer (score 2):

Hybris [cache region](https://help.hybris.com/1808/hcd/8c392bd686691014ae1bf4af383a81d5.html) is bonded with the type system, means you can specify a region for a type to store its entities.

So with the OOTB standards, you can't simply specify a region for the single query. Better you choose right [evictionPolicy](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.7/apis/cache-eviction-algorithms.html) (LFU).

But yeah, the feature called TTL helps you. Refer to [this post](https://hybrisdiary.com/2017/12/11/flexible-search-caching-with-ttl/)

Comment: There is also a cache region for flexible search queries and others.

Comment: Yes, it's there, but @Sayed wants to keep separate region for a single query.